Azure DevOps: Unable to Access PowerShell Output Variable in Template - Variable Not Resolving in Template
I'm having trouble accessing an output variable from a PowerShell task in my Azure DevOps pipeline and passing it into a deployment template. When I set the variable in a PowerShell script and try to pass it into my template, it doesn't resolve as expected.
The issue is that the variable $(filteredWebsitesPath) in my template is not resolving to the expected value. Instead, it just prints as $(filteredWebsitesPath) instead of the actual paths or values I need.
trigger:
- main

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

stages:

- stage: Build
  displayName: 'Build Stage'
  jobs:
  - job: BuildJob
    steps:
      - task: Npm@1
      - task: Npm@1
      - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
        inputs:
          PathtoPublish: 'build'
          ArtifactName: 'drop'


- stage: Deploy
  displayName: 'Deploy to Production'
  dependsOn: Build
  condition: succeeded()

  jobs:
  - deployment: PreDeployJob
    displayName: 'PreDeployJob'
    environment: 
      name: 'Production'
      resourceType: VirtualMachine

    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
          - task: PowerShellOnTargetMachines@3
            displayName: 'Get Website Names'
            name: GetWebsites
            inputs:
              Machines: 'ip:port'
              InlineScript: |
                  $websites = Get-ChildItem -Directory -Path 'C:\myPath\' | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name
                  $filteredWebsites = $websites -join ','
                  Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=filteredWebsitesNew;isOutput=true]$filteredWebsites"
          - script: echo "Output: $(GetWebsites.filteredWebsitesNew)"
            name: echovar

  - job: SetVariableJob
    displayName: "Set Variable for Template"
    dependsOn: PreDeployJob
    variables:
      filteredWebsitesPath: $[ dependencies.PreDeployJob.outputs['PreDeployJob.GetWebsites.filteredWebsitesNew'] ]
    steps:
    - script: echo "Filtered Websites Path $(filteredWebsitesPath)"      

  - template: templates/deploy-template.yml
    parameters:
      filteredWebsitesNew: $(filteredWebsitesPath)


And here’s the template, where I’m trying to use filteredWebsitesNew:
parameters:
  filteredWebsitesNew: ''

jobs:
- ${{ each website in split(parameters.filteredWebsitesNew, ',') }}:
  - deployment: DeployJob
    displayName: 'Deploy to ${{ website }}'
    environment: 
      name: 'Production'
      resourceType: VirtualMachine
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
          - script: echo "Deploying to website ${{ website }}"


Despite setting the variable in the SetVariableJob, it isn’t being resolved when used in the deploy-template.yml template. Instead, I see $folderPath = "C:\myPath$(filteredWebsitesPath)\images" in the logs, where $(filteredWebsitesPath) doesn’t resolve to the actual variable value.
What am I missing, or is there an alternative way to ensure the variable resolves correctly in the template?
I tried setting the output variable filteredWebsitesNew in a PowerShell task within the PreDeployJob and expected it to resolve in the deploy-template.yml template. In SetVariableJob, I referenced the output variable using dependencies syntax and passed it to the template as $(filteredWebsitesPath). I expected the template to receive the resolved paths, but instead, it printed the literal variable name $(filteredWebsitesPath) without resolving it to the actual paths.

so like what is put here
      filteredWebsitesNew: $(filteredWebsitesPath)

it will directly send this to template without resolving
so when i access this then it look like below $folderPath = "C:\myPath\$(filteredWebsitesPath)\images"

Also getting script output like "Deploying to website $(filteredWebsitesPath)" for script in template ```steps:
- script: echo "Deploying to website ${{ website }}"


You can not pass parameters like this, The each expression is rendered at compile-time which is before runtime, and the variable $(filteredWebsitesPath) has not yet been generated.

I have gone through the link but didn't get complete idea that how it is useful in my case  , will you please tell that where and what exactly I need to change to get my Yaml working  @RanadipDutta

then how to pass parameters in my case @wenbo

In short, as I was mentioning earlier, "You cannot pass parameters as there is no variable initiation happening at runtime." So the check in the template if you can hardcode or read it from somewhere before runtime.

@RanadipDutta your link is irrelevant - variables in ARM templates have nothing to do with Azure Pipelines variables.

As mentioned in the comments, template expressions such as ${{ each ... }} are compiled before the pipeline starts and before the output variable is set.
If you want to run each deployment in parallel I suggest you create a dedicated pipeline for the deployments, that is triggered after the output variable is set.
For example, consider a pipeline named deploySomething:
parameters:
  - name: filteredWebsitesNew
    displayName: 'A comma separated list of websites to deploy'
    type: string

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

# Disable CI-CD trigger
trigger: none

jobs:
- ${{ each website in split(parameters.filteredWebsitesNew, ',') }}:
  - job: DeployJob_${{ website }}
    displayName: 'Deploy to ${{ website }}'
    environment: 
      name: 'Production'
      resourceType: VirtualMachine
    steps:
    - script: echo "Deploying to website ${{ website }}"
      displayName: 'Deploy to ${{ website }}'

After setting the output variable in the original pipeline you can configure a job to trigger the deploySomething pipeline as follows:
jobs:
  - deployment: PreDeployJob
    displayName: 'PreDeployJob'
    environment: 
      name: A
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
            - pwsh: |
                $filteredWebsites='foo,bar'
                Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=filteredWebsitesNew;isOutput=true]$filteredWebsites"
              name: GetWebsites
            - script: |
                echo "Output: $(GetWebsites.filteredWebsitesNew)"
              name: echovar

  - job: TriggerBuild
    displayName: 'Trigger Build'
    dependsOn: PreDeployJob
    # don't run this job if the output variable 'filteredWebsitesNew' is not set / is empty
    condition: >-
      and(
        succeeded(),
        ne(dependencies.PreDeployJob.outputs['PreDeployJob.GetWebsites.filteredWebsitesNew'], '')
      )
    variables:
      filteredWebsitesPath: $[ dependencies.PreDeployJob.outputs['PreDeployJob.GetWebsites.filteredWebsitesNew'] ]
    timeoutInMinutes: 3
    cancelTimeoutInMinutes: 1
    steps:
      - checkout: none
      - script: |
          echo "Filtered Websites Path: $(filteredWebsitesPath)"
        displayName: 'Show variable'
      - pwsh: >-
          $run=$(
          az pipelines run
          --name "deploySomething"
          --organization $(System.CollectionUri)
          --project $(System.TeamProject)
          --branch $(Build.SourceBranchName)
          --parameters filteredWebsitesNew="$(filteredWebsitesPath)"
          --output json) | ConvertFrom-Json

          $pipelineUrl = "$(System.CollectionUri)$(System.TeamProject)/_build/results?buildId=$($run.id)"

          Write-Host "##vso[task.logissue type=warning]Pipeline was triggered. Web URL: $pipelineUrl"
        displayName: 'Trigger the deployment build'
        env:
          AZURE_DEVOPS_EXT_PAT: $(System.AccessToken)

The script uses the azure pipeline run command of the Azure DevOps CLI. As an alternative, you can use the Trigger Build Task for more advanced scenarios.
Please note you might need to configure the new pipeline's permissions for the user/group that is running the build:


Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

As of now I have just hardcoded the branch name  but want to fetch this at runtime @Rui

@AdityaRanjan if both pipelines are supposed to run on the same branch you can use pipeline variable $(Build.SourceBranchName); otherwise, you'll have to hard-code the branch name or use a variable.

while creating new pipeline it always create new branch , how to create new pipeline with old branch so that i can put both pipeline on same branch ? @Rui

@AdityaRanjan add the new YAML pipeline file manually in the same branch as the old pipeline and then see steps in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59067096/create-a-new-pipeline-from-existing-yml-file-in-the-repository-azure-pipelines

https://quickcoder.org/azure-create-pipeline/

Just wanted to know that Is it possible to trigger multiple pipelines here , by providing (,) separated pipeline names - pwsh: >-           $run=$(           az pipelines run           --name "deploySomething"           --organization $(System.CollectionUri)    @Rui

@Ranjan according to the documentation of az pipelines run (see link above) it is NOT possible to trigger multiple pipelines with a single command.

I am facing an issue when triggering a pipeline using the az pipeline run command. If the pipeline involves two site names, the deployment for the second site only starts after the first one is completed, meaning parallelism is not achieved. This is a concern because I have around 40–50 sites in the filteredWebsitesPath, and the current setup will take a significant amount of time to complete. @Rui

@Ranjan that depends on how you configured the pipeline. Just remember that jobs by default run in parallel but stages by default run sequentially. My sample pipeline works as expected, If you try it you'll be able to run jobs in parallel.
